# Trouble while connecting my WCF service to ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application regarding a bookstore. I have created a database, and included some books inside. My original ASP.NET application works just fine and I'm able to view my books, in Books page that I have created. In that page I'm able to see their name, thumb image, and price along with a link saying "Add To Cart", which in turn when pressed puts the book in the cart that I have created.

Then I created a WCF service, where I want to have my book catalog as a service. I added a .dll reference of my original project to my WCF service application, and here is the files in my service, with a single service that I want to implement.

**Catalog.svc.cs**

```
public class Catalog : ICatalog
{
    public IQueryable<Bookstore.Models.Book> GetBooks()
    {
        var _db = new Bookstore.Models.BookContext();
        IQueryable<Book> query = _db.Books;

        return query;
    }
```

**ICatalog.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICatalog
{
    [OperationContract]
    IQueryable<Book> GetBooks();
}
```

Then I created a third project, another ASP.NET Web Forms application, where I want to use my previously created WCF project, and display the catalog of my first project in my current third ASP.NET project. I created a new page called Catalog where I want my books from the first project to be displayed. I already added the service reference of my previous WCF service, and also added the reference .dll file of my first ASP.NET application. Below you can find the code about my Catalog file, that I created in my third project. Please note that the .aspx file is completely the same as my first projects .aspx file where my books were displayed. Please note that in my third project's Catalog.aspx.cs file, as you can see below I have created a new instance of my previously  created WCF service, and used the method there to display the books.

**Catalog.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Books" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeBehind="Catalog.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookstoreServiceImplementation.Catalog" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Page.Title %></h1>
            </hgroup>

                 <section class="featured">
                    <ul> 
                        <asp:ListView ID="bookList" runat="server"
                            DataKeyNames="BookID"
                            GroupItemCount="3" ItemType="Bookstore.Models.Book" SelectMethod="GetBookData">
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>      
                                <table id="Table1" runat="server">        
                                    <tr>          
                                        <td>No data was returned.</td>        
                                    </tr>     
                                </table>  
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>  
                            <EmptyItemTemplate>     
                                <td id="Td1" runat="server" />  
                            </EmptyItemTemplate>  
                            <GroupTemplate>    
                                <tr ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">      
                                    <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>    
                                </tr>  
                            </GroupTemplate>  
                            <ItemTemplate>    
                                <td id="Td2" runat="server">      
                                    <table>        
                                        <tr>          
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>          
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("BookByNameRoute", new {bookName = Item.BookName}) %>">
                                                    <image src='/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ImagePath%>'
                                                        width="75" height="100" border="1"/>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("BookByNameRoute", new {bookName = Item.BookName}) %>">
                                                    <%#:Item.BookName%>
                                                </a>       
                                                <br />
                                                <span class="BookPrice">           
                                                    <b>Price: </b><%#:String.Format("{0:c}", Item.UnitPrice)%>
                                                </span>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>        
                                        </tr>      
                                    </table>    
                                </td>  
                            </ItemTemplate>  
                            <LayoutTemplate>    
                                <table id="Table2" runat="server">      
                                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">        
                                        <td id="Td3" runat="server">          
                                            <table ID="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">            
                                                <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>          
                                            </table>        
                                        </td>      
                                    </tr>      
                                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server"><td id="Td4" runat="server"></td></tr>    
                                </table>  
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </ul>
               </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Catalog.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
using Bookstore.Models;

namespace BookstoreServiceImplementation
{
    public partial class Catalog : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void GetBookData()
        {
            CatalogReference.CatalogClient catalog = new CatalogReference.CatalogClient();

            catalog.GetBooks();
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is as follows, when I open run my third project, and enter to the Catalog page, instead of seeing the books from my first project, I get only a text saying: "No data was returned."
If someone can help me solve this problem, I would be glad.

Comment: This `and also added the reference .dll file of my first ASP.NET application` shouldn't be unnecessary, and would probably cause alot of ambiguity problems. The types needed from the service will be exposed in the wsdl definition, and recreated in your new client asp.net application.  (Removed my first comment so I could be a little more clear)

Comment: @asawyer If I don't do it, I get an error in my Catalog.aspx file, in the parts regarding "Item", while as I have written my Catalog.aspx file is nearly the same as the page in my original ASP.NET application where my books are displayed.

Comment: The types you need `Book` ect, should exist in the namespace created when you added the service reference. Check with the object browser.

Comment: @asawyer I tried removing it from the using statement, and also from the References part. But when I try to compile my third project, now I get an errors in Reference.cs file, regarding the parts that use my first Bookstore project.

Comment: Well you got me then, I dont have your project in front of me to look more into it. As for why there isn't any data, you have some debug options. Is the new site on the same localhost? Are you using basic http bindings? Fiddler2 should show the request/response traffic. Verify that the calls are going to the right place.

Comment: @asawyer Sites are at different localhosts.

Comment: it would be nice if you return json from your webservice and parse that json at your client end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing wcf services and wcf dataservices.

A standard wcf service cannot return a truly queryable IQueryable.  Essentially, it just ToLists the IQueryable (pulling down every row in the database) and sends it across the wire as a collection.  On your client, you see the evidence of this as you are receiving an array of books.

If you wish to be able to send filtered queries over the wire to the server using IQueryable, you need to use wcf data services.  Data services uses an IQueryable on the client to generate rest requests to the server which relay the intent of you query.  The server receives the arbitrary query and returns the data.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe GetBookData should not be void, it should return an IQueryable. Try

```
    public IQueryable<Book> GetBookData()
    {
        CatalogReference.CatalogClient catalog = new CatalogReference.CatalogClient();

        return catalog.GetBooks();
    }
```

Comment: If I do like that, I get an error saying: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Bookstore.Models.Book[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Bookstore.Models.Book>'

Comment: Sorry, I left the List in the web service. You just have to either use IQueryable everywhere or IList everywhere. I've modified my answer again to reflect your initial code.

Comment: I get the same error message. When I hover over my GetBooks function in my Catalog file, it says: Book[] CatalogClient.GetBooks(). I don't know why it gets it as a book filetype.